# AlarmManager or WakefulBroadcastReceiver doesn't work when screen is locked AND app is in background on some devices

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

EDIT: Since I posted the question I've tested the app on numerous devices and also on emulator and apparently the problem wasn't with the app but with the phone I was testing it at the beginning. But now I am curious why on some phones `AlarmManager` or `WakefulBroadcaastReceiver` (I don't really know which one is it) doesn't work  when app is in the background and screen is locked. Can I somehow fix it via code or in device's options?
I will also add that the phone that I was testing it on and wasn't working was Huwaei P8 Lite with Android 5.0.1

Original question:

I am using `AlarmManager` in my app to display notifications in some time intervals. It works fine when app is open or when the app is in background ( for example after I press home button). It also works when I lock phone screen while app is active. But when I lock the phone when my app is in the background my `BroadcastReceiver` isn't being called by `AlarmManager`. Why is that? The problem is even in AlarmManager or maybe rather in my receiver?

Also I have bonus question: Is it possible for my alarm in AlarmManager to work after app is killed?

Here is my code:

```
public class NotificationService extends IntentService {

public NotificationService(String name) {
    super(name);
}
public NotificationService() {
    super("NotificationService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {                 
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this).setContentTitle("TEXT")
                .setContentText("TEXT")
                .setLights(Color.GREEN,1000,500)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_event_white_24dp).getNotification();
        notificationManager.notify(0,notification);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent i = new Intent(this,AlarmReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,i,0);
            long nextAlarm = System.currentTimeInMillis()+1000*60;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo alarmClockInfo = new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(nextAlarm, pi);
            alarmManager.setAlarmClock(alarmClockInfo, pi);
            }else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            alarmManager.setExact(android.app.AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nextAlarm, pi);
            }else {
            alarmManager.set(android.app.AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nextAlarm, pi);
            }            

           AlarmReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}
```

Receiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {    
    Log.e("test","onReceive started");    
    Intent i = new Intent(context,NotificationService.class);               
    startWakefulService(context,i);
}
}
```

When the screen is locked and app is in the background receiver is never started since i cant see the line : `Log.e("test","onReceive started");` executed

I do have WAKE_LOCK permission in manifest

Answer (score 0):

You can check an excellent example of using AlarmManager [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8801990/4451655)

> Is it possible for my alarm in AlarmManager to work after app is killed?

`AlarmManager` is intended to work even after the app is killed.

Comment: Use the code in the link.. It should not happen... you might be doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Permissions to manifest and add the functionality on your notification IntentService to verify that your notification is fired.

So you can use a JobScheduler service:

```
JobScheduler jobScheduler =
                (JobScheduler) getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);

        if (!enabled) {
            jobScheduler.cancel(JOB_ID);
            Log.d(TAG, "cancelling scheduled job");
        } else {
            long interval = AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY;
            JobInfo job = new JobInfo.Builder(JOB_ID,
                    new ComponentName(getPackageName(),
                            ScheduledJobService.class.getName()))
                    .setPersisted(true)
                    .setPeriodic(interval)
                    .build();

            jobScheduler.schedule(job);
            Log.d(TAG, "setting scheduled job for: " + interval);
```

And

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public class ScheduledJobService extends JobService {
@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
    startService(new Intent(this, NotificationService.class));
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: I do have WAKE_LOCK permission

Comment: I don't want to use JobScheduler because I want my app to work on devices previous to API 21